# Accessing realtime firebase object in react.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently trying to access the value within our Joblist object. We are unable to do joblist[0].company which should return google.

What is the best way to access the values of our object?

Our joblist object contains:
key: value 
company: "Google" 
datePosted: "2021-09-20T05:00:00.000Z"
location: "San Francisco" 
position: "SWE Intern"

```
[{ 
  "company" : "Google", 
  "datePosted" : "2021-09-20T05:00:00.000Z", 
  "id" : 0, 
  "location" : 
  "San Francisco", 
  "position" : "SWE Intern" 
}]
```

App.js code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
      
      super(props);
    
      this.state = {joblist : []}
    }
      
    componentDidMount() {
      firebase.database().ref("1h5GOL1WIfNEOtcxJVFQ0x_bgJxsPN5zJgVJOePmgJOY/Jobs").on("value", snapshot => {
        let jobs = [];
        snapshot.forEach(snap => {
            // snap.val() is the dictionary with all your keys/values from the 'students-list' path
            jobs.push(snap.val());
        });
        this.setState({ joblist: jobs });
      });

    }
    render(){
    const {joblist} = this.state;
    // console.log(joblist[0].datePosted)
    console.log(joblist);

    return ( 
      <div id='body'>
        

        <Header />
        <PhoneInput />
        <TableHeader />
        <Table joblist = {joblist}/>
        <Footer />
      </div>
      
    );
  }
  }
  export default App;
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the exact JSON from `1h5GOL1WIfNEOtcxJVFQ0x_bgJxsPN5zJgVJOePmgJOY/Jobs` in the database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: [ {
  "company" : "Google",
  "datePosted" : "2021-09-20T05:00:00.000Z",
  "id" : 0,
  "location" : "San Francisco",
  "position" : "SWE Intern"
} ]

Comment: That all looks good to me. Are you saying that the code you shared doesn't work? If so, is there an error? The one thing that jumps out to me is the commented out `console.log(joblist[0].datePosted)`, which will give an error initially as the array will still be empty. To catch that you'll need to do `if (joblist.length > 0)  console.log(joblist[0].datePosted);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one thing that jumps out to me is the commented out `console.log(joblist[0].datePosted)`, which will give an error initially as the array will still be empty. To catch that you'll need to do:

```
if (joblist.length > 0) console.log(joblist[0].datePosted);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define your joblist, make sure that it is declared and defined as an empty array when your app initiates. this would prevent any issues of pushing items to it through the state manager.

Console logging the whole object from the snapshot `val()` may also yield inside to the object since Arrays are not natively supported, this could be the case if you are using UID's for each entry but are not unpacking the data first.